# iMac hard freezes intermittently after booting off an external SSD

Tags: hard-drive, imac, usb, ssd, performance

I have hooked up an external USB3 Samsung T5 SSD to my iMac model `iMac14,2`, formatted it as APFS, and installed macOS High Sierra on it, to use as my primary system drive.

I can use the system for a week, maybe a week and a half, at a time, but after a while my machine will hard freeze as I am using it - as in, can't move the mouse or type with the keyboard, screen is frozen.  It usually happens when I'm doing something disk-intensive, like opening the fuzzy file browser in Visual Studio Code, or opening a file browser, but I have a suspicion that it has frozen and then rebooted on its own while I was away from the system at least once.

I checked the console and didn't see anything jump out at me in that span of time where the system froze.  I ran First Aid on the disk itself and the disk container, but the only warning I got was `warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device: (7723705+1) bitmap address (10e2e)`

The only other thing that might be relevant is that something that I noticed that happened once or twice in the past week is that my keyboard suddenly stopped working - no keys would cause an action - but my mouse that is hooked up to my keyboard would continue to work.  Strange.

I am currently using three of the four USB ports available in the back - one has the Samsung SSD, another has the keyboard/mouse hooked up, and a third has my Time Machine spinning-rust HDD hooked up to it, which does not have its own power cable.

Comment: did you try `Option, Command, and Esc (Escape)` and then FORCE quit apps one at the time

Comment: I think I might have tried that at some point, but I'm not certain.